# webview turns nil after calling function from another controller

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview

Hello if anybody can help me thanks!
I got two viewcontrollers `HomeController` and `TableController`
In HomeController i got a webview and when i go to the TableController and call a function to load an another request for the webview. The webview returns nil. 
The HomeController is the main screen of the application which is a webview. The TableController is a table from a hamburger menu left of the application. When i open it and click on an item, I want to get the url of that item and use that url to send a request with the same HomeController. But at the moment when i reach `connectUrl()` i get an fatal error and it is because the webView is nil.

edit: answer below

Code below:

TableController

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var HomeViewController: HomeController {
        return self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("homeController") as! HomeController
    }

    let url = self.item[indexPath.item].url

    HomeViewController.connectUrl(url!)
}
```

HomeController

```
class HomeController: UIViewController{
static let sharedInstance = HomeController()

var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let preferences = WKPreferences()
    preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true

    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.preferences = preferences

    webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: configuration)

    self.view.addSubview(self.webView)
}
func connectUrl(url: String){
    let url2 = NSURL(string: url)
    let req = NSURLRequest(URL: url2!)
    print(req)
    self.webView!.loadRequest(req)

}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after trial and error with many development options like delegates, segue, instantiateViewController etc.

In the end NSNotificationCenter was the solution for me.

I created this function in my `TableController` to send a notification to the `HomeController` to call ConnectUrl.

```
func sendData(url: String){
       self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
       let itemDictionary = ["itemUrl": url]
       NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("connectUrl", object: nil, userInfo: itemDictionary)

        }
    }
}
```

In the `HomeController` I added an Observer to receive the noticatification and unpack the dictionary is received to get the url.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: configuration)

    self.view.addSubview(self.webView!)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "connectUrl:", name: "connectUrl", object: nil)
}
func connectWithSpecifiedItem(notification: NSNotification){

    let itemUrl = notification.userInfo!["itemUrl"] as! String

    let url2 = NSURL(string: itemUrl)

    let req = NSURLRequest(URL: url2!)
    self.webView!.loadRequest(req)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any domain erron in console?/
 if yes

add it to plist.

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but if the function is called there aren't any domain errors.

Comment: Yes, as in the description. I get an error when the function `connectUrl()` is called. It is a fatal error and says that the webview = nil.

Comment: Just pass constant string instead of url lke: https://www.google.com and try if it works letme know.

Comment: Sorry, does not work. I tried using NSnotifcationcenter and completion handlers, but no succes yet. It has to do with the webview, because if i replace `self.webview!.loadrequest(req)` with `self.webview?.loadrequest(req)` it loads the request but it does not have a webview.

Comment: @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!
try making outlet and connect from stoaryboard and try load webview

Comment: if I replace my WKWebView with UIWebView I just get a blackscreen and webview is still nil.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a `WKWebView` related issue. The actual problem here is that you don't know how to return data from a view controller.

The most basic solution for this is a delegate. First, create a `TableControllerDelegate`.

```
protocol TableControllerDelegate {
   func tableController(tableController: TableController, didSelectItemWithURL: NSURL)
}
```

Then you implement this in your `HomeController`:

```
class HomeController: UIViewController, TableControllerDelegate {
   func tableController(tableController: TableController, didSelectItemWithURL url: NSURL) {
       webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
   }
}
```

In your `TableController`, things get a little simpler and less connected. You let it have a TableControllerDelegate field and simply call that to pass the selected item URL back to whatever view opened it.

Note that there is no direct relationship between `TableController` and `HomeController` anymore. This is a good practice.

```
class TableController: UITableViewController {
    weak delegate: TableControllerDelegate?
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let url = self.item[indexPath.item].url
        delegate?.tableController(self, didSelectItemWithURL: url)
    }
}
```

Now when you present your `TableController` from your `HomeController` you simply configure its delegate:

```
func displayTableController() {
    let tableController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tableController") as! TableControllerController
    tableController.delegate = self
}
```

More code, but this is a very common pattern in iOS.